# Find which row a short array is in a longer array

Tags: excel

I have two columns, one with set values, another with values retrieved from user inputs.

What I want to do is figure out where the user is based on the values entered.

In the example, set values are column A, user values are column B.

[image: Columns]

The user's array starts at row 10 and loops into row 3. Where it loops is not important. What's important is to know that the user is at row 10.

If it has multiple references (for example they only entered 2,1,3) it should show multiple rows. (7,10).

Comment: What have you tried?  What is the problem with your solution?  As written, I don't know what you are trying to do, but the above may clarify. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I can't figure anything out. I don't even need a solution just a starting point. An excel function that returns a row depending on a set of inputs instead of one value. For example the function MATCH() should do what I'm asking but it takes a single item in a column.

Comment: I still don't have a clue as to what you want to accomplish, but `INDEX` with a `0` for *column_num* argument will return the row specified by *row_num*